# Why does width of confidence interval increases with trend

Tags: distributions, bayesian, confidence-interval

I am trying to understand bayesian statistics. I am familiar with machine Learning and the way that best fit is made through loss function. I am stuck with the concept of uncertainty in coefficients.

Suppose I have a simple model, where y=trend*x, and the trend coefficient is normally distributed like,

[image]

Now suppose I have, following data points and I multiply distribution by the data points, the results that i would get would be as follows:

[image]

As I go further up the trend, my uncertainty increases, why is this the case, How would such analysis help in practical way? Am i making the right conclusions.

Comment: Almost the opposite question asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596537/how-are-the-confidence-intervals-calculated-in-the-hw-function-the-the-forecas *"I would expect the size to increase as you predict further into the future as you become more uncertain of your predictions"*